# Convert date in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert this date:

```
2011-11-02T10:41:43+0000
```

Into this using JavaScript:

```
02/11
```

Thankful for all help!

Comment: It seems that 02/11 is `DD/MM` (might be `DD/YY` though?), and 2011-11-02T10:41:43+0000 is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+TZ`; this should be possible with string processing. Alternately, do you have the date as a JS Date object? You could call yourobject.getMonth() and yourObject.getDate() .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that date is a string, a simple [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) can offer the desired results:

```
var date = "2011-11-02T10:41:43+0000";
date = date.match(/-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})T/);
date = date[2] + "/" + date[1]; // date = "02/11"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = new Date('2011-11-02T10:41:43+0000'),
    dateString = d.getDate()+'/'+(d.getMonth()+1);

console.log(dateString); // 2/11
```

Comment: `11/2011` ? That doesn't look right...I think you meant `d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth()` . Also, I'm getting `NaN/NaN` in some browsers, might be locale-dependent?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
var d = new Date('2011-11-02T10:41:43+0000');
var e = d.getUTCDate() + '/' + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1);
alert(e);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pRbZ2/

*Assuming that the **11** you want is the month and not the year*